# How to use selectors in Mobile App using Appium

Tags: android, ios, css-selectors, appium, inspector

I am trying to inspect an Android/iOS app .

When i inspect an android app, I get the following:-

```
resource-id: com.company.droid.qa:id/textNewsDate

class:- android.widget.TextView

package:- com.company.droid.qa
```

Will package name will be added in resource-id across all ids in app ?

For Some element, i did't see the text only see the id. Can i know why ?

Using: UIAutomatorViewer to inspect an android app

Is there any better tool to inspect an android/ios app in linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

UIAutomator is good to find the locator of an element. The reason you don't see text/ID for some elements because your developers didn't add it for that element. You can ask your developer to modify it as per your need.